# disnake.errors.DiscordServerError: 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

Sometimes an error

`disnake.errors.DiscordServerError: 503 Service Unavailable (error code: 0): upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: overflow`

appears in my discord bot and the function stops working. Is there any way to fix this?

Code:

```py
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def players_task(self):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(Config.BOT_PLAYERS_CHANNEL)
        last_message = await channel.history(limit=1).flatten()
        server_status = server.reconnect()

        res = server.server.response.decode('utf-8').replace('\x01', '').replace('\x03', '')
        players_list = f"\n".join(f"`{nickname.strip()[:-2]}`" for nickname in res.split('?')[1:])

        embed = Embed(
            title=f" [{len(res.split('?')[1:])}]{Config.BOT_SEPARATOR}Players",
            description=players_list,
            color=Colour.dark_green(),
            timestamp=datetime.now(),
        )

        if last_message and last_message[0].author == self.bot.user:
            await last_message[0].edit(embed=embed)
        else:
            await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I do not know what to do

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.